# Adjust the scrollview height dynamically at runtime

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I am developing a react-native project.

I have a `ScrollView` in `MyComponent`, the content of `ScrollView` consists of :

- a `MySubComponent`,
- a `Text`
- a `Image` component

All the content/data of above components have dynamic length or height. So, I would like adjust the content height of my `ScrollView` on the fly at runtime.

To achieve that my plan is to disable `automaticallyAdjustContentInsets` of the `ScrollView` as you can see from my below code snippet. Then, have a state variable to hold the latest value of `contentInsetBottom`. But I am not sure how can I calculate the height of child components so that I can call `setContentInsetBottom(totalHeight)` to update the content height of my `ScrollView` .

(I am pretty sure my plan will work if I know how to calculate the height of each child component of my `ScrollView`.)

Anyone can guide me a bit?

```
const MyComponent = ({myText, image}) => {

   // I have a state of the contentInsetBottom for the ScrollView
   const [contentInsetBottom, setContentInsetBottom] = useState(0);

   // how can I get the height of each children component, sum them up & call setContentInsetBottom(totalHeight) here ?

   return (
   <ScrollView
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        contentInset={{top: 0, bottom: contentInsetBottom}}
        style={styles.scrollView}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>

        <MySubComponent />
        <Text>{myText}</Text>
        <Image source={{uri: image?.uri}}>
   </ScrollView>)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap all content inside the `<ScrollView>` in a `<View>`. Then use onLayout to get the height of that parent View.

```
  const handleScrollContentLayout = (e) => {
    const { height } = e.nativeEvent.layout
    setScrollLayoutHeight(height)
  }

...

<View onLayout={handleScrollContentLayout}>
{ /* scrollView content... */ }
</View>
```

Then you can use the scrollLayoutHeight as per your needs to set the height at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. It works, however, the content height looks doubled than the actual content overall. I have to `setScrollLayoutHeight(height*0.5)` in order to avoid big empty space at the bottom of the ScrollView content.

Comment: console.log the height value and check if its changing. Usually, the onLayout gets called more than once and the final value is often the right one. In my case, I was receiving 0 at first render. Therefore, I set the returned height into state with the useState hook to update accordingly.

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation#measurecallback -> Check out this callback as well. It's another option to get height dynamically. Though, I've not used it before.